Using tcolorbox to produce a box for section in mathematical writing
I'd like to write my math notes with a little ornament, and I find the box below is good, I try to read the documentation of the tcolorbox package but ultimately giving up since the documentation is really hard to read and locate the info I want, is anyone who have create section box like this?
Thanks a lot! (I suspect every math students will feel motivated when the notes is beautiful! instead of being stuck in a single exercise lol)


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This might not be the answer you'd expect, but in my opinion the tcolorbox package is really a bit too heavy for this. I would suggest that you try with the titlesec package instead which also handles all the necessities for setting up section titles in a proper way.
In fact, there is a very similar example on page 21 of the current version of the package manual next to the relevant code. I changed it a bit to make it even more similar to what you show in the picture:
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}[frame]
    {\color{cyan!50!black}\normalfont}
    {\filright\small\enspace SECTION \thesection\enspace}
    {8pt}{\large\bfseries\filcenter}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{3}
\setcounter{section}{2}

\section{Some Other Decent Methods}

Foo bar baz

\end{document}



If you really want to use tcolorbox (I would not), you would need to tell LaTeX how to handle the internal references and bookmarks and also to remove the indentation after the box. In all, there is much more to think of and it is easy to overlook something which titlesec would handle out of the box. In reference to this nice answer you could do something like the following:
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\sectionbox}{ m }{
    \refstepcounter{section}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\string\numberline{\thesection}#1}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        enhanced,
        colback=white,
        arc=0pt,
        boxrule=.4pt,
        colframe=cyan!50!black,
        coltext=cyan!50!black,
        width=\linewidth,
        halign=center,
        valign=center,
        fontupper=\large\bfseries,
        title={SECTION \thesection},
        coltitle=cyan!50!black,
        attach boxed title to top left={
            xshift=7pt,
            yshift=-7pt,
        },
        boxed title style={
            size=fbox,
            colback=white,
            colframe=white,
        }
    ]{#1}
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \@afterindentfalse\@afterheading
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{3}
\setcounter{section}{2}

\sectionbox{Some Other Decent Methods}

Foo bar baz

\end{document}



Thanks! I tried titlesec which is enough for my lightweight use.
